# Pass result of mysql_fetch_object() to a function does not work

Tags: php, mysql

I have the following problem:

```
public function row2Partner($row){
  echo $row->PartnerID;
}

public function main(){
  $query = "SELECT PartnerID, PartnerName FROM Partner";
  $result = mysql_query($query);
  $this->row2Partner(mysql_fetch_object($result));
}
```

This gives me the error in r`ow2Partner()`:
Trying to get property of non-object

But `$row` is an Object! And if I do
echo `$row->PartnerID` in the main function, it works.

Any ideas?

Thx,
Martin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your result returns more than one row, your object is going to be multi-dimensional. I'm pretty sure you can do something like this if you just want to echo the first one:

```
public function row2Partner($row){ echo $row[0]->PartnerID; }
```

If you are looking for only one result, I would also limit my query to just one...

```
SELECT PartnerID, PartnerName FROM Partner LIMIT 1
```

If you want to echo out all your rows (in the case of multiple) results, you can do this:

```
public function row2Partner($row){ 
    foreach($row as $result) {
        echo $result->PartnerID; 
    }
}
```

Hope that helps.

**PS**
Just as a sidenote, I tend to like to use associative arrays when dealing with MySQL results--it just makes more sense to me. In this case, you would just do this instead:

```
mysql_fetch_assoc($result)
```

Comment: Looks good. This works great - I had the problem that the function got called twice, once with valid $row data, once with an empty one.
Thanks a lot for the quick reply.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that mysql_query() has executed the query successfully, and also that there is actually a row being returned? It might be worth checking it, e.g.

```
//check query executed ok
if ($result = mysql_query($query)) {
    //check there is actually a row
    if ($row = mysql_fetch_object($result)) {
        $this->row2Partner($row);
    } else {
        //no data
    }
} else {
    //error
    die(mysql_error());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Best thing I can think of is that you may need to pass by reference rather than by value. Change your function declaration to

```
public function row2Partner(&$row)
```

Hope that helps,
David